# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool issues even If I used using statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on dotnet core 3.1. I am working on API call.

When I call the API, below function in Repository will execute first by saving the data:

[image]

then another function will get execute by getting all saved data

[image]

Result of this API call I have got below:

[image]

However using statement will prevent these kind of issues but even If I used using statement though I have getting these issues.

Comment: try open connection in the method. use using, so close connection once done.

Answer (score 1):

wrap in sql connection. this is example

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]))
                    {
                        conn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand($"truncate table tablename", conn))
                        {
                            dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                        }
                        dr.Close();

}
```